# Estimote didChangeAuthorizationStatus not called if isn't in ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, localization, estimote

I want call `startMonitoringForRegion` in method `didChangeAuthorizationStatus` and everything works fine, basically because code is copied from `Estimote` Example. This code is in `ViewController`. Issue occurs when I'm using similar code but placed in separated controller.

This code works fine and method `didChangeAuthorizationStatus` also `didStartMonitoringForRegion` is called every time so I open app or changeStatus. So success.
**ViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    self.region = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:[[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"myUUID"]
                                                     identifier:@"EstimoteSampleRegion"];
    self.beaconManager = [[ESTBeaconManager alloc] init];
    self.beaconManager.delegate = self;

    [self startRangingBeacons];
}

-(void)startRangingBeacons
{
    if ([ESTBeaconManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined)
    {
        [self.beaconManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }
    else if([ESTBeaconManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Location Access Denied"
                                                        message:@"You have denied access to location services. Change this in app settings."
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
    }
    else if([ESTBeaconManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Location Not Available"
                                                        message:@"You have no access to location services."
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}

- (void)beaconManager:(id)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status
{
    if (status != kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined && status != kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied )
    {
        [self.beaconManager startMonitoringForRegion:self.region];
    }
}

- (void)beaconManager:(id)manager didStartMonitoringForRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region{
    NSLog(@"didStartMonitoringForRegion %@",region);
}
```

This code works partially. Method `requestAlwaysAuthorization` in `BeaconManager` is calling once but then `didChangeAuthorizationStatus` is not even when I've manually called `startMonitoringForRegion` then method `didStartMonitoringForRegion` is not called.

### **Separeted BeaconManager**

**ViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    self.region = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:[[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"myUUID"]
                                                     identifier:@"EstimoteSampleRegion"];
    self.beaconManager = [[BeaconManager alloc]initWithRegion:self.region];
    [self.beaconManager startMonitoring];

}
```

**BeaconManager.swift**

```
class BeaconManager: NSObject,ESTBeaconManagerDelegate {
    private lazy var secureBeaconManager:ESTSecureBeaconManager = {
        let beaconManagerForReturn = ESTSecureBeaconManager()
        beaconManagerForReturn.delegate = self
        return beaconManagerForReturn
    }()
    private lazy var beaconsArray = [CLBeacon]()

    var region:CLBeaconRegion!
    var delegate:BeaconDelegate?

    init(region:CLBeaconRegion) {
        super.init()
        self.region = region
    }

    /**
    Method which check AuthorizationStatus for application, and will start monitoring if status is equal .AuthorizedAlways
    */
    func startMonitoring() {
        setupLocalizationAuthorization()
    }

    private func setupLocalizationAuthorization(){
        let status = ESTSecureBeaconManager.authorizationStatus()
        if (status == .NotDetermined){
            secureBeaconManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        }

        if (status == .Denied){
            delegate?.beaconManager(self, locationAutorizationFail: .Denied)
        }

        if (status == .Restricted){
            delegate?.beaconManager(self, locationAutorizationFail: .Restricted)
        }
    }


    // MARK: - BeaconManager

    func beaconManager(manager: AnyObject, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        if (status != .NotDetermined && status != .Denied){
            secureBeaconManager.startMonitoringForRegion(region)
        }
    }
    func beaconManager(manager: AnyObject, didStartMonitoringForRegion region: CLBeaconRegion) {
        print("didStartMonitoring for \(region)")
    }
}
```

**Question**

Why this is happening? It's thread issue? I have no clue what's going wrong here. From I can see both codes are similar but instructions are placed in different place. It's no matter If I use Swift or Obj-c (tried it already).

Answer (score 1):

Analyze what happens when you start the app for the first time:

You instantiate your `BeaconManager` and call `startMonitoring`, which in turn calls `setupLocalizationAuthorization`. In there, you check the authorization status of your app, and if it's *NotDetermined*, you instantiate `secureBeaconManager` (because you declared it a lazy property), assign the delegate (via your lazy-instantion code), and call `requestAlwaysAuthorization`. This prompts the user to allow the app to access Location Service, and if they agree, iOS issues a call to `didChangeAuthorizationStatus` with the new, *Always* status, and you finally you start monitoring. This flow, as you mentioned, works as intended.

Consider however the flow where the app already has the *Always* authorization:

You instantiate your `BeaconManager` and call `startMonitoring`, which in turn calls `setupLocalizationAuthorization`. In there, you check the authorization status of your app. But you have no `if` clause for *Always* status … so the `BeaconManager` simply finishes there.

**Solution**: append an `if` clause for the *Always* status to your `setupLocalizationAuthorization`:

```
if status == .AuthorizedAlways {
    secureBeaconManager.startMonitoringForRegion(region)
}
```

Let's do one final pass over what happens when you implement the proposed solution:

You instantiate your `BeaconManager` and call `startMonitoring`, which in turn calls `setupLocalizationAuthorization`. In there, you check the authorization status of your app. If it's *Always*, you lazy-instantiate the `secureBeaconManager`, and start monitoring. The previous flow (for *NotDetermined*) stays the same.

Comment: All you wrote it's true besides that part when after user agreed to Localization Service and `didChangeAuthorizationStatus` is called. In fact it is not and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Do you have any other call to `requestAlwaysAuthorization` in your code? If you did, the status would be changing before your `BeaconManager` gets lazy-instantiated, and thus it wouldn't receive this call.

Comment: I didn't thought about it. After quick search I've founded one more request `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` in other `ClassA`. This class also implements method `didChangeAuthorizationStatus`. I've changed `BeaconManager` to not lazy and how it goes. `ClassA` init -> request for localization -> `BeaconManager` init -> request for localization -> Class A gets `didChangeAuthorizationStatus` -> BeaconManager not getting notification. Is this correct behaviour ?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. If `ClassA` requests location before `BeaconManager` is initialized, the latter won't know about it. The solution I suggest, to explicitly check for the `.AuthorizedAlways` when you're starting monitoring, should solve exactly that.